# prismatic joint not workin with ros2_control?

Tags: ros-humble, gazebo-ros2-control

HI everyone i have the following code:

```
<!--///////////////////////////AUFBAU DES FÖRDERBANDES///////////////////////////////////-->

<!--link name="root_link"/>
<joint name="root_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="1 0 0.035" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="root_link"/>
    <child link="belt"/>
</joint-->

<link name="belt">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.5 3 0.15" />
        </geometry>
        <material name="belt">
            <color rgba="0.3 0.3 0.3 1" />
        </material>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.4 0 0.0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="50"/>
        <inertia ixx="${(50/12)*(0.15*0.15+0.5*0.5)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${(50/12)*(3*3+0.5*0.5)}" iyz="0.0" izz="${(50/12)*(0.5*0.5+0.15*0.15)}"/>
    </inertial>

    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0.4 0 0.0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.5 3 0.15" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>
</link>


<link name="cube">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="belt">
            <color rgba="0.5 1.0 0.5 1" />
        </material>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="0.05"/>
        <inertia ixx="10" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="10" iyz="0.0" izz="10"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
</link>



<joint name="BeltPrismatic" type="planar">
    <origin xyz="0 -1 0.16" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent link="belt" />
    <child link="cube" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit effort="100" velocity="50" lower="-1" upper="1" />
</joint>


<!--////////////////////////////////////////Gazebo-Eigenschaften///////////////////////////////////////////-->
 <gazebo reference="belt">
    <material>Gazebo/DarkGrey</material>
</gazebo>
<gazebo reference="cube">
    <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
</gazebo>

<ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
        <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
    </hardware>
    <joint name="BeltPrismatic">
        <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-1.0</param>
            <param name="max">1.0</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    </joint>
</ros2_control>
```

and the following controller:

```
    belt_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - BeltPrismatic
    command_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
    state_publish_rate: 100.0
    action_monitor_rate: 20.0
    allow_partial_joints_goal: false
    constraints:
      stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.01
      goal_time: 0.0
      BeltPrismatic: { trajectory: 0.01, goal: 0.1 }
```

and i try to get the joint to move with this code:

```
    import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectory, JointTrajectoryPoint


class BeltSpeedController(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('BeltSpeedController')
        self.publischer = self.create_publisher(JointTrajectory, '/belt_controller/joint_trajectory', 10)
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(Float64, 'given_belt_velocity', self.velocity_callback, 10)
        self.get_logger().info('BSC gestartet...')




    def velocity_callback(self, msg):
        velocity = msg.data
        self.get_logger().info('Geschwindigkeit erhalten: {}'.format(msg.data))

        self.trajMsg = JointTrajectory()
        self.trajMsg.joint_names = ['BeltPrismatic']
        point = JointTrajectoryPoint()
        point.positions = [1.0]  # Die gewünschte Position hier ende des förderbandes
        point.velocities = [velocity]  # Sie können dies je nach Anforderung anpassen
        self.trajMsg.points = [point]
        self.publischer.publish(self.trajMsg)
        self.get_logger().info('Geschwindigkeit und Punkt umgesetzt: {}, {}'.format(velocity, point))


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = BeltSpeedController()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Unfortunately the Cube wont move along the joint and just rest at its position, how can i get it to move. Note: The Controller and all Nodes are starting without any errors

Answer (score 0):

Prismatic joints work for sure, see the [gazebo_ros2_control_demo](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/gazebo_ros2_control/doc/index.html) package.

Your yaml file is missing the controller manager part. See this example how to setup [Gazebo classic simulation](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_9/doc/userdoc.html).

If you just missed to copy the whole file, please also add your launch file and possibly the output from `ros2 control list_controllers`